# MVC3 Custom Route has issues with Virtual Directory

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this in my global

```
 //custom route
 routes.MapRoute(
      "DownloadInstall", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{logonserver}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Software", 
           action = "DownloadInstall" }  // Parameter defaults
 );

 //custom route
 routes.MapRoute(
      "DownloadHelp", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{logonserver}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Software", 
          action = "DownloadHelp" }  // Parameter defaults
 );

 //default route
 routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Software", action = "Index", 
           id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

and I invoke custom routes in javascript (which works great) like this:

```
 window.location.href =  '/Software/DownloadHelp/' + @Model.ID +'\/' + 
      getLogonServer();
```

However, as soon as I moved this to an IIS7 box which has a virtual directory, my default routes were smart enough to prepend with the virtual name...however my javascript based routes aren't found because the virtual directory isn't prepended.

Comment: And that's why you should use the `Html`, `Ajax` and `Url` helpers  to generate your links...

Comment: Sergi...thx...I tried that but wasn't able to get the javascript variable to form correctly I tried this window.location.href = @Url.Action("Software", "DownloadInstall", new RouteValueDictionary(new {id = @Model.ID, getLogonServer()}), null);

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use the `Url` helper if I were you, but I realize the javascript function result will be a problem.
I'm not sure if that will work, but you could try and build up your link like this:

```
var server = getLogonServer();
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadHelp", "Software", 
    new { Model.Id, logonserver = ""})' + '/' + getLogonServer();
```

What definitely would work is making `getLogonServer()` an Html helper function instead of a javascript function, but I don't know if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using @Url.Content helper as such:

```
window.location.href =  '@Url.Content("~/Software/DownloadInstall/")' + @Model.ID +'\/' + getLogonServer();
```